# Json call not implementing in android

Tags: android, json

I was trying to make json calls to the database.I have create two classes to get the contacts from the database which is at the server.But the code does not seem to work.Please help me with this.

My activity.java file is as follows:-

```
package com.example.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {


    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = null;
       // Making HTTP request
       try {
           // defaultHttpClient
           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
           if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
              // parsing JSON
               json = new JSONObject(retSrc); //Convert String to JSON Object
           }


       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


       // return JSON String
       return json;

   }
    }
   /* public void writeJSON() {
          JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
          try {
            object.put("name", "Rock");
            object.put("score", new Integer(200));
            object.put("current", new Double(152.32));
            object.put("nickname", "Programmer");
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.out.println(object);
        } 
*/
```

My contacts activity is as follows:-

```
package com.example.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ContactActivity extends Activity 
{

//url to make request
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.100:3000/users.json";

private static int users;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "first_name";
private static final String TAG_MIDDLE = "middle_name";
private static final String TAG_LAST = "last_name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_MOBILE = "mobile";

private static final int TAG_USERS = users;



// users JSONArray

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tab_test1);

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

// Getting Array of Contacts

JSONArray users = null;
// looping through All Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = json.optJSONObject(i);

// Storing each json item in variable

// creating new HashMap

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

String id = null;
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
map.put(TAG_ID,id);
String first = null;
map.put(TAG_FIRST, first);
String middle = null;
map.put(TAG_MIDDLE, middle);
String last = null;
map.put(TAG_LAST, last);
String address = null;
map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
String mobile = null;
map.put(TAG_MOBILE, mobile);

String email = null;
map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);

// adding HashList to ArrayList
userList.add(map);
}

}
}
```

The debugger is stopping at `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);` in activity.java file, and the application stops/crashes when I run it

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-json-parsing-example.html

Comment: please go though this link

Comment: if you haven't added permission in manifest,add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and let me know if it works,i will make it as answer .

Comment: Use [**GSON**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You will have to add a library to your project.

Comment: if still issue exists mail me i will solve you issue at inbox.viditmathur@gmail.com

Comment: @vidit i tried the link which u had given ..I am able to call the sever.But the values are not displayed in the emulator and i am not getting any sort of error

Comment: please send log cat details what your got after making a web call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but you should be running http operation on different Thread

Like this:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSON parser = new JSON(getJSONfromURL(url));
                    }
                }).start();
```